# Adding namespace to XML Digital Signature

Tags: xml, saml-2.0, xml-signature

I'm signing a SAML token with an X509 certificate, and getting what looks like a good signature except for one issue that seems relatively small, but that is causing me a huge headache.  My signature looks like this:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="#[removed]">
         <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
         </Transforms>
         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
         <DigestValue>S4...ku4=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
   </SignedInfo>
   <SignatureValue>oav...T7E=</SignatureValue>
   <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
         <X509Certificate>MII...KFl</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
   </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

What I need is to add a namespace, ds, so that the signature looks like this:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <ds:Reference URI="#[removed]">
         <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
         </ds:Transforms>
         <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
         <ds:DigestValue>S4...ku4=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
   </ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:SignatureValue>oav...T7E=</ds:SignatureValue>
   <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
         <ds:X509Certificate>MII...KFl</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

It seems like this should be something I could do during while computing the signature or importing the signature block back into the existing XML document, but, for the life of me, I can't figure out how I should be doing it. I've searched online and found several people having this issue, but haven't found a good example on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Your original version is already "namespaced", thanks to the xmlns attribute on the Signature element.  Why do you need the extra clutter of colonified names?

Comment: Unfortunately, the receiving vendor needs the extra clutter.  It's certainly not my choice.

Comment: That's very strange, unless your consumers are using some home-grown XML parsing suite.  E.g. did they insist on the prefix specifically being 'ds' too?  OTOH, if it could be anything - i.e. they are in fact using a XML namespace aware package - then it could be nothing, exactly as the defaulting rules support.  Can you ask them _why_ they "need" the unnecessary clutter?  Maybe a workaround can be negotiated.

Comment: You could also try post-processing your output with an XSLT stylesheet [along these lines](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/50335-adding-prefix-nodes-subnodes-output-xml.html#post182627).  But I still think negotiating a sensible solution is superior.

Answer (score -1):

Since all tags need that starting namespace, you can try to treat the signature as a string with vb.net, c# or java, or any other compiler, and use a string.replace method. I give you an example with vb.net:

```
Dim signature as string = 'place here your file with a stringreader
signature = signature.Replace("<", "<ds:") 'first, all tags
signature = signature.Replace("<ds:/", "</ds:") 'then we correct closing tags
```

Hope it helps

Comment: However, I would not recommend manually altering a signature, since it may be detected as falsified.